# Plugin I made reports java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to call a class that starts a websocket in another file when the Minecraft plugin runs, but I'm getting an error.
What's the problem?
please help me..
(use maven)

```java
package test.minecraft;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class test_Minecraft extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        this.saveDefaultConfig();
        chat backchat = new chat();
        backchat.st();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }

}
```

```java
package test.minecraft;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class chat {
    private static WebSocketClient client;

    public static void st(String chatId) {
        connectWebSocket();

    private static void connectWebSocket(S) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("wss://example.com");
            client = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
                @Override
                public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                    System.out.println("Connected to websocket");
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String s) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    System.out.println(s);

                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                    System.out.println("Connection closed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
            client.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call a class that starts a websocket in another file when the Minecraft plugin runs.

Comment: please add the complete stacktrace to your question and also how you exactly start Minecraft with your plugin.

Comment: Please describe how do you build (i.e. Maven, Gradle, etc) and its build script (i.e. pom.xml, build.gradle, build.gradle.kts).

Comment: <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: please don't add xml snippets in comments, rather put them into your question - it's better formattable there (and we will help you to do that if necessary)